# Simply connected holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

How can we show that if $f$ is holomorphic on a region $D$, and has no root in $D$ ($D$ is simply connected), then $g:D\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic such that for every $z\in D$, $ g^n(z)=f(z)$

Alot of the exercises in my notes use this result, but I was just wondering why is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f'/f$ is holomorphic on the simply connected domain, let $\phi$ be its primitive, then $\dfrac{d}{dz}(fe^{-\phi})=0$, and hence $fe^{-\phi}=c$ for some constant $c\ne 0$. And then $f=e^{\phi+c'}$. Now we let $g=e^{(\phi+c')/n}$.

\begin{align*}
(fe^{-\phi})'=f'\cdot e^{-\phi}-f\cdot e^{-\phi}\phi'=f'e^{-\phi}-f\cdot e^{-\phi}\cdot\dfrac{f'}{f}=0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you, now can I ask, why is $\frac{d}{dz}(fe^{-\phi})=0?$ with the relation with primitive part? I would appreciate some more elaborate explanation to this part.

Comment: How is $\phi$ defined? I understand the algebra, but I do not understand the definition of $\phi,$ is it $\log f?$

Comment: Do you know the theorem that for a simply connected domain every holomorphic function has primitive?

Comment: Essentially it is $\log f$, but the definition of it somehow needs to be taken care, so avoid it.

Comment: No, I dont think I have seen that theorem before. I do not understand what "primitive" in this case here means.

Comment: The function which derivative is $f$.

Comment: So if we let $\phi = \log f$ be primitive, then the derivative of $\phi$ is not $f$ since it would be $f/f'?$

Comment: Nevermind I got it now , thank you :)